# Twilio - forward call to another (non-Twilio) IVR

Tags: twilio

I am trying to use Twilio webhooks and constructing response using TwiML and need to do following:

IVR A (non-Twilio) forwards a call to our Twilio webhooks and for some scenarios, we would like to forward the call to original IVR A. Is this supported out-of-the-box using Twilio verbs?

I tried using Dial to forward the call to original IVR but in this case, Twilio call is in progress and gets completed when the original call ends. is it possible to forward the call and hang up immediately to complete Twilio call?

```
com.twilio.twiml.Number number = new com.twilio.twiml.Number.Builder("XXXXXXXXXX").build();
                    return new VoiceResponse.Builder()
                            .say(say)
                            .dial(new Dial.Builder().number(number).build())
                            .hangup(new Hangup())
                            .build();
```

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Once a call has come into a Twilio number and is under control by Twilio, then it will continue to be a call until it is all over. When you make it `<Dial>` Twilio remains part of the call (and you can gain control over it again using it's call SID and the REST API). If you were to hang the Twilio call up, since it was in charge of dialling the external IVR it would also hang up that connection.